# How do I display the total amount of the value of every text area?

Tags: javascript, html, textfield

I have this code that if the checkbox is checked the value of the checkbox will be multiplied to the value of the dropdown list and will display the product to the text field. How will I display the total of each text field into a textfield.

```js
function special1() {
            var m = document.getElementById("check1").checked;
            var x = document.getElementById("check1").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("qty1").value;
            var z = 0;
            if (m == true) {
                z = "P" + x * y;
            }
            document.getElementById("total1").value = z;
        }
        function special2() {
            var m = document.getElementById("check2").checked;
            var x = document.getElementById("check2").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("qty2").value;
            var z = 0;
            if (m == true) {
                z = "P" + x * y;
            }
            document.getElementById("total2").value = z;
        }
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <h2><font color="white">Specialty Cakes</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <center>
                <img src="special\blackforest_small.jpg"><br>
                <font color="white">
            Black Forest</td>
        <td><font color="white">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value="550.00" onclick="special1()">Buy P550.00</input><br>
            <input type="text" id="total1" name="total1" value="P0.00" size="8"></input><br>
            <font color="white">QTY:
                <select id="qty1" name="qty1" onchange="special1()">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <center>
                <img src="special\chocolata_small.jpg"><br>
                <font color="white">Chocolata</center>
        </td>
        <td><font color="white">
            <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2" value="550.00" onclick="special2()">Buy P500.00</input><br>
            <input type="text" id="total2" name="total2" value="P0.00" size="8"></input><br>
            QTY:
            <select id="qty2" name="qty2" onchange="special2()">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Looks like you've some code already. Please explain what it does differently than you want.

Comment: Please explain it in better way. Your code has many errors

Comment: I want to put another text field for the total amount of the id total1 and total2. It means every time the total field will change its value, the grand total will sum all its values.

Comment: Due to some reason m unable to post answer.

Comment: But your first textbox field value is non Numeric i.e. P0.00

Comment: var total = total(total1,total2);
and then document.getElementById("total").value = total
function total(total1,total2){
       return total1+total2;
    }

Comment: I inputted the codes but still not working. here is the code were the total will be displayed.
<p><center><font size="5">Total Amount: <input type="text" id="grand" name="grand" value="P0.00"></input></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should validate your HTML code using w3cvalidator before posting.  I have modified your code to work it properly.

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><h2>Specialty Cakes</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="special/blackforest_small.jpg"/>   
        <br />Black Forest
     </td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value="550.00" />Buy P550.00<br /><input type="text" id="total1" name="total1" value="P0.00" size="8"><br />
QTY: <select id="qty1" name="qty1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="special/chocolata_small.jpg" /><br />Chocolata</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2" value="550.00" />Buy P500.00<br /><input type="text" id="total2" name="total2" value="P0.00" size="8" /><br />
QTY: <select id="qty2" name="qty2">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        var total = $(this).siblings('input:text');            
        var dropdown = $(this).siblings('select');
        total.val('p'+( $(this).val()*dropdown.val() ));
    }
});

$('select').change(function(){

    var total    = $(this).siblings('input:text');
    var checkbox = $(this).siblings('input:checkbox');
    if(checkbox.is(':checked'))
    {
        total.val('p'+( $(this).val()*checkbox.val() ));
    }
});

 });
</script>
```

Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qhuLrvjn/

Pure Javascript Code:

```
    <script>
    var firstVal = 0.00;
    var secondVal = 0.00;
    function special1() {
            var m = document.getElementById("check1").checked;
            var x = document.getElementById("check1").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("qty1").value;
            var z = 0;
    if (m == true) {
                z = "P" + x * y;
                firstVal = x * y;
     }
    else
    {
       z = "P"+"0.00";
       firstVal = 0;
    }
            document.getElementById("total1").value = z;

    document.getElementById("grand").value = 'P'+(firstVal + secondVal);
        }

    function special2() {
            var m = document.getElementById("check2").checked;
            var x = document.getElementById("check2").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("qty2").value;
            var z = 0;
    if (m == true) {
                z = "P" + x * y;
                secondVal = x * y;
     }
    else
    {
      z = "P"+"0.00";
       secondVal = 0;
    }
            document.getElementById("total2").value = z;
                document.getElementById("grand").value = 'P'+(firstVal + secondVal);
        }

</script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><h2>Specialty Cakes</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="special/blackforest_small.jpg"/>   
        <br />Black Forest
     </td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value="550.00" onchange="special1()" />Buy P550.00<br />
    <input type="text" id="total1" name="total1" value="P0.00" size="8" /><br />
QTY: 
   <select id="qty1" name="qty1"  onchange="special1()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="special/chocolata_small.jpg" /><br />Chocolata</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2" value="550.00" onchange="special2()" />Buy P500.00<br /><input type="text" id="total2" name="total2" value="P0.00" size="8" /><br />
QTY: <select id="qty2" name="qty2" onchange="special2()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3">Total Amount: <input type="text" id="grand" name="grand" value="P0.00" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks Apul but I only need to use HTML and Javascript with this.

Comment: jQuery provides you a clean way to bind events. Any specific reason for not using jQuery?

Comment: i'm still a student and we're still learning HTML and Javascript

Comment: I understand. I have added Javascript version of code as well. You can check that. :)

Comment: there isn't any total amount box for the total value of both total. I forgot to add another text box in it.

Comment: it worked. i'll just input it to my full code. thanks